# React MUI v5 Card background has a white background with 5% Alpha and i don't know where it is from

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

It looks like this

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05))
```

in a class named
`.css-18bsee0-MuiPaper-root-MuiCard-root`
So it's something from MUIs Card or MUIs Paper, it's not in my code as far as i can tell.

i assume i triggered it somewhere. My theme looks unsuspicious too.

i found it when i was overriding the background on a condition with a gradient from red to 'paper.background` and the color didn't match evene if the hex code was the same ('#424242').

It's in all Card Components,e ben those that are not yet modified with my added gradient.

Any idea how to get rid of that or apply it to my gradient too?

PS: A screenshot for firefox dev tools:

[image: dev tools of the background image css prop]

Comment: set `background: #424242;` to override all background props

Comment: i tried that in the theme with `   MuiPaper: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          background: '#424242',
        },
      },
` but that's too much. cvhanges backgrounds of children too.  Haven't found the right place yet.

Comment: And my AppBar has the same pale white layer. Look's like it comes from `Paper`...
The html tree has a paper related css but my code has no Paper..

Answer (score 2):

Found it in the docs: [Change dark mode background opacity](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#paper)

> Change the background opacity based on the elevation in dark mode.
> This change was made to better conform to the Material Design guidelines.
> You can revert it in the theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiPaper: {
+     styleOverrides: { root: { backgroundImage: 'unset' } },
    },
  },
});
```

comment #1 had the right direction, just the implementation needed tweaking...

Comment: You legend! This has been driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this below on your style with important tag

```
.css-18bsee0-MuiPaper-root-MuiCard-root{

     background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1))!important
}
```

Comment: Perhaps my question was unclear. i want that style gone. And the css is generated by MUI so i can't modify it directly.

Comment: If you want to get rid of that style you can set alpha 0 with top style params and important tag

Answer (score 0):

Add this as a prop in your component

```
sx={{
   [`&.MuiCard-root`]: {
      //your styles
      borderRadius: "25px" //For example changing 4px to 25px in border radius
   }
}}
```